# Linking a website through Disqus comment

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, post, hyperlink, comments, disqus

I am doing this application on Ruby on Rails 3 from which you could reply to a comment posted on any blog. At the end of the comment, I added something like this: 'Posted through MyAppName'

But my question is: How can I link MyAppName to my website? So something along "Posted through [MyAppName](http://myappname.com)

So far I was able to do this: 'Posted through http://MyAppNam.com'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer was very trivial actually:

```
<a href="myapp.ca">My App Name </a>
```